# gcc error? couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.3.0'

Tags: gcc, d

I realise there are quite a few similar questions on Stack overflow with a similar header. However, mine is different because:

(1) it reports kern.osversion '14.3.0' and not '14.0.0'

(2) I manage to successfully install the latest gcc version through homebrew (version gcc 4.0.2_1).

This is the problem: 
I want to install a package from source (the 'largeQvalue' package, [ref](http://biorxiv.org/content/early/2014/10/06/010074)).
After successfully installing the gcc and gsl libraries, which are required for compiling the package, I get the error pasted below after I type the `make` command.

Previous related questions suggested updating the gcc libraries after having updated your computer, however the latest gcc and Xcode command line tools are already installed.

In order to possibly reproduce the following error, I used the following pipeline:

clone the git repository, after installing the gcc and gsl libraries:

git clone https://github.com/abrown25/qvalue

cd to the 'qvalue' folder

run `make`

Interestingly, also when I request the gdc version `gdc --version`, the same error pops up:
`gdc --version couldn't understand kern.osversion 14.3.0 i686-apple-darwin9-gdc-4.0.1 (GCC) 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5484)`

```
make
gdc -frelease -finline-functions -O3 -Werror -Wall -fversion=Have_largeQvalue src/largeQvalue.d src/parse_arg.d src/bootstrap.o src/libspline.a -lblas -lgsl -    lgslcblas -lm -o bin/largeQvalue
couldn't understand kern.osversion `14.3.0'
src/largeQvalue.d:29: found '..' when expecting ')'
src/largeQvalue.d:29: found ')' when expecting ';' following 'statement'
src/largeQvalue.d:35: found 'double' when expecting ';' following 'statement'
src/largeQvalue.d:35: found '!' when expecting ';' following 'statement'
src/largeQvalue.d:38: found '!' when expecting ';' following 'statement'
src/largeQvalue.d:38: semicolon expected, not '/'
src/largeQvalue.d:38: found '/' instead of statement
src/largeQvalue.d:40: found '!' when expecting ';' following 'statement'
src/largeQvalue.d:40: found '-' when expecting ')'
src/largeQvalue.d:40: semicolon expected, not 'e'
src/largeQvalue.d:40: found ')' when expecting ';' following 'statement'
src/largeQvalue.d:40: found '/' instead of statement
src/largeQvalue.d:104: found 'import' instead of statement
src/largeQvalue.d:113: found '..' when expecting ')'
src/largeQvalue.d:113: found ')' when expecting ';' following 'statement'
src/largeQvalue.d:125: expression expected, not '>'
src/largeQvalue.d:125: found 'a' when expecting ')' following 'template argument list'
src/largeQvalue.d:125: semicolon expected, not ')'
src/largeQvalue.d:125: found ')' instead of statement
src/largeQvalue.d:126: semicolon expected, not '~'
src/largeQvalue.d:126: found '~' instead of statement
src/parse_arg.d:11: semicolon expected, not 'helpString'
src/parse_arg.d:11: no identifier for declarator helpString
src/parse_arg.d:80: semicolon expected, not 'versionString'
src/parse_arg.d:80: no identifier for declarator versionString
src/parse_arg.d:84: no identifier for declarator pure
src/parse_arg.d:84: semicolon expected, not 'this'
make: *** [bin/largeQvalue] Error 1
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: FYI: GCC is up to version 4.9.something now, and are working on version 5.

Comment: As for your problem, please include relevant code as it's really hard to say anything without guessing (and probably very badly) about the errors.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the latest gcc version I am able to install through home-brew would be the version mentioned above, as issueing `brew upgrade gcc` returns `Error: gcc 4.9.2_1 already installed`, unless there is something I am not aware of.

Comment: Then you already *had* the latest version. You could easily have checked by going to the [GCC homepage](https://gcc.gnu.org/) and used `gdc --version` to get the version number.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks again, for the reply. Interestingly, also when I request the gdc version, the same error pops up:

`gdc --version`

`couldn't understand kern.osversion 14.3.0 `

`i686-apple-darwin9-gdc-4.0.1 (GCC) 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5484)`

Comment: I am having a similar problem with gcc 4.9.0 in BigSur 11.16.2. Simply `gcc --version` and I get " gcc: warning: couldn’t understand kern.osversion ‘20.6.0 " . I just open a new question about it (because the kern.osversion is similar, not the same). Also, I tried the `xcode-selec --install` fix, but it did not worked for me.